# can I serve multiple models thru the same port using MLflow?

Tags: port, endpoint, mlflow, mlops

I was reading about the [deployment tools](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#built-in-deployment-tools) you get out of the box when using MLflow.

It seems you can serve a model from the registry by doing something like

`mlflow models serve -m runs:/<run_id>/model <some server>:<some port>`.

and then, you send some data and get back a prediction by doing

```
curl http:/<some server>:<some port>/invocations -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "inputs": {<some data>}
}'.
```

This is great but does this mean you can only serve one model on one port? Is this a best practice or a technical limitation or not the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can serve any model using MLflow, if you want to use a single endpoint for multiple models you can package all your models into a single model using pyfunc module and deploy this one. [Here](https://github.com/manuelgilm/data_science-portafolio/tree/master/machine_learning/model_serving_mlflow) an example of this.

In that example, there are two models, and wrapper is created around these models, then, during inference time we choose which model get predictions from using input parameters.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/machine-learning/model-serving/serve-multiple-models-to-serving-endpoint) you can also find an example published for Azure Databricks